# Good practice to use all SysML Diagrams?

Tags: uml, modeling, sysml

is it good practice to use all diagrams of SysML in one project, or is it even **required** to use all diagrams for a complete SysML model?

Let's take an example project, where a customer uses an online calculator.
A complete Behavior Diagram model includes Use-case, Sequence Diagram, Activity Diagram, and State Diagram.

Starting with a Use-Case Diagram would show the customer interacting with the online calculator which he can use and "calculate".
A Sequence Diagram would show the customer send data to the  online calculator, and wait until results are send back.
I could then use a Activity Diagram to show which data comes in and which goes out. Something like "data_in --> process --> data_out".
With a State Diagram I could show that the online calculator "waits for incoming data" and is triggered into "process" state, not accepting incoming data during "process".

You see, the diagrams are quite redundant and with little to none additional information.

Should I go for it, or is this a diagram overkill?

Answer (score 2):

You create as many diagrams as you need to transport your thoughts. The model is the important part. The diagrams are just graphic views on the model that help humans to understand it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the different between _model_ and _diagram_. Anyway, you say I don't have to use all SysML diagrams. It's still a true and legitimate SysML model engineering, even though I don't use all SysML diagrams in that one project?

Comment: As said: use just those diagrams you really need. Not more. But even more important: not less.